# How to nest xsl:for-each selec

Tags: xml, xslt, nested, foreach

HI!

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<Dokument>
        <Skupina id="3">
            <Naziv_skupine>RAZSTAVNI PROSTOR</Naziv_skupine>
                    <Dvorana id="295">
                    <Naziv_dvorane>DVORANA  C</Naziv_dvorane>
                        <Postavka id="41">
                            <Artikel>1105</Artikel>
                        </Postavka>
                    </Dvorana>

                    <Dvorana id="281">
                    <Naziv_dvorane>DVORANA A</Naziv_dvorane>
                        <Postavka id="41">
                            <Artikel>1102</Artikel>
                        </Postavka>
                    </Dvorana>
        </Skupina>


        <Skupina id="86">
            <Naziv_skupine>UPORABNINA PROSTORA, TEHNIČNE OPREME IN OSEBJA</Naziv_skupine>
                    <Dvorana id="295">
                    <Naziv_dvorane>DVORANA  C</Naziv_dvorane>
                        <Postavka id="41">
                            <Artikel>2100</Artikel>
                        </Postavka>
                    </Dvorana>
        </Skupina>


</Dokument>
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">

    <xsl:for-each select="Dokument/Skupina">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="7" valign="top"><xsl:value-of select="Naziv_skupine"/></td>
        </tr>

        <xsl:for-each select="/Dokument/Skupina/Dvorana">
      <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="7" valign="top"><xsl:value-of select="Naziv_dvorane"/></td>
      </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Dokument/Skupina/Dvorana/Postavka">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><xsl:value-of select="Artikel"/></td>                      
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>

    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
RAZSTAVNI PROSTOR
  DVORANA C
    1105
    1102
    2100
  DVORANA A
    1105
    1102
    2100
  DVORANA C
    1105
    1102
    2100
UPORABNINA PROSTORA, TEHNIČNE OPREME IN OSEBJA
  DVORANA C
    1105
    1102
    2100
  DVORANA A
    1105
    1102
    2100
  DVORANA C
    1105
    1102
    2100
```

But I want the result like this:

```
RAZSTAVNI PROSTOR
  DVORANA C
    1105
  DVORANA A
    1102
UPORABNINA PROSTORA, TEHNIČNE OPREME IN OSEBJA
  DVORANA C
   2100
```

Where do I get wrong?

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 5):

In the second for-each, try changing this path

```
/Dokument/Skupina/Dvorana/Postavka
```

to

```
./Postavka
```

You want to continue the second for-each loop at the node the first one is pointing at.  What you're doing is re-selecting all nodes from the root, since you specify /Dokument/....

Comment: its not for me. Still getting the first one of the nested for each